# Lexical error vs syntax error in C

Tags: c, compilation, syntax-error, lexical-analysis

Consider line number 3 of the following C-program.

```
int main() {            /*Line 1 */
int I, N;               /*Line 2 */
fro (I=0, I<N, I++);    /*Line 3 */
}
```

Identify the compiler’s response about this line while creating the object-module:

1. No compilation error
2. Only a lexical error
3. Only syntactic errors
4. Both lexical and syntactic errors

---

My attempt :

`Line 3` has `fro` instead of `for` keyword of C. Since, lexical analyzer doesn't bother about wrong keyword, that job of syntax analyzer to ensure correct syntax or keyword (i.e. `for()` instead of `fro()`). Lexical analyzer does tokenization of of program.

> Can you explain in formal way please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fro` will not match a keyword, but the lexing will go OK and `fro` will be classified as an identifier.

At the parsing stage, `fro (I=0, I<N, I++)` will be transformed to a function call with three arguments. Note that modifying and reading the `I` variable within the same sequence point is undefined behaviour.

During the scope analysis the compiler will complain that no such function exists, or, in case the compiler treats unseen functions as implicitly declared, the linker will complain that there is an undefined reference to a function.

Comment: The compiler will most certainly warn that `fro` is undeclared though.

Comment: @Blagovest, yes it gives [error](http://cpp.sh/9hrlp) error: `'fro' was not declared in this scope`. Is it syntax error or semantic error?

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: it's really a semantic error. Although it is an invalid program, it conforms to the syntax of the language.

Comment: I would go for "no compilation error", although most modern compilers frown upon implicitly declared functions. The compiler would generate the object file, but the linker will be unable to resolve the `fro` reference in the object code.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. I got it :).